# How to Seprate wso2 xacml policy in tenent envirnament based on Registry

Tags: ldap, xacml, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-identity-server

Our  requirement  is  that  i  have  to  separate  xacml  policy  file  from  default  registry  called  wso2Registry.

so ,  i  am  trying  to  do  this  scenario  using  wso2-Governance  Registry

but  i  cant  get   succeded  on  this

is  anythings  other  then  i  have  to  do  to  seprate  xacml  policy  based  on  Tenent  so  that  one  tenent  cant see  other  Tenent  Xacml  policy  file  not  even  super  tenent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your requirement is to isolate the entitlement(XACML) policy. You don't need a separate WSO2 G-Reg instances to do that. In default you it will save the policy at following path for all the tenant, and all the tenants have their own registry space. Therefore any other tenant/ super tenant cannot access them. /_system/governance/repository/identity/entitlement/policy/pap